# Risc processor the Negation of a register

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, instruction-set, risc

We consider a RISC processor that have only a few command like DBNZ. I am trying to write code that writes the negation of a Register A into B and also second separate code that it should subtract A from B and  put the result into C

I am not sure how to do it I don't really maybe it could be possbile with Nasm Assembler but those are two different things  but not sure how to start

Comment: _Which_ RISC processor? There are many, and their instruction sets differ.

Comment: @Michael very simple Risc Processor... I found now that the Subtracting could works with Bit-flipping and adding 1 => NAND and ADDI

Comment: @Michael how to write NAND+1 of A into B

Comment: Very simple? How simple? What are the available instructions?

Comment: @Michael ok  only DBNZ =>  Derement and Branch if not Zero

Comment: It would be trivial with NASM, because NASM is an x86 assembler.  `neg eax`.  Done.  Most RISCs have a subtract instruction and often a zero-register, e.g. MIPS `sub $v0, $zero, $a0` implements `retval = 0 - arg`.  Any practical real-world CPU will have at least a sub and an efficient way to zero a register.  ARM even has a reverse-subtract (since it has no zero-reg), but it's not as RISCy as most RISCs.  `rsb r0, r0, #0` does `r0 = 0-r0`

Answer (score 3):

For the record, real RISC architectures (e. g. ARM or MIPS) are richer than DBNZ. What you envision is usually designated as an OISC or a URISC.

NASM, by the way, would be of no help. It only targets real life CPUs; yours is an academic model. But putting together an emulator in a high level language would be rather trivial. I can probably write one in JavaScript in an hour or so.

The syntax I'm assuming for its only command is:

```
DBNZ reg[, label]
```

and the meaning is:

```
reg = reg - 1
if label is given and reg != 0 then goto label
```

If label is omitted, the implicit jump target is just the next instruction. It's a lump of syntactic sugar for me, for better code readability.

Everything after semicolon to the end of the line is a comment. Labels are terminated with colon. My code assumes that registers have finite size, and integer wrap-around happens quietly, without exceptions.

---

The algorithm for negation is easy enough:

```
b=0
while a > 0
    a = a-1
    b = b-1
```

In assembly, the conditional jump and the decrement are one and the same. So it would go like this:

```
;Zero out B
BZeroLoop:
DBNZ B, BZeroLoop ; Decrement until it's zero

;Main loop: subtract from A until it's zero, decrementing B on every iteration
NegLoop:
DBNZ B ; Decrement B with no jump
DBNZ A, NegLoop
```

Now the subtraction. The algorithm for subtracting B from A in place (i. e. result stays in the A register) goes:

```
while b != 0
    b = b-1
    a = a-1
```

It's in fact the same loop as in negation, but without the initial zeroing out. You can think of negation as of a case of subtraction in place - specifically, it's subtracting from zero.

But we need the result to go into c. In a less stunted language, we'd just assign. But we don't have assignment. It's possible to do assignment with two negations and a temp register. But we can make do with one negation - first, calculate b-a in place, then negate it to c:

```
while a != 0
    a = a-1
    b = b-1 ;this reduces b to the value of b-a

c = 0 ; also a loop

while b != 0
    b = b-1
    c = c-1
```

Or, in assembly:

```
SubLoop: ; B = B-A
DBNZ B
DBNZ A, SubLoop

CZeroLoop: ; C = 0
DBNZ C, CZeroLoop

NegLoop: ; C = C-B
DBNZ C
DBNZ B, NegLoop
```